Why does vert.x return 401 in a non-reactive HTTP API Gateway v2 + Cognito + Lambda Quarkus app?
I have a Quarkus (3.12.3) AWS lambda application deployed as a Java 21 zip package (for SnapStart, which doesn't support containers as of writing). I'm using AWS HTTP v2 API gateway (payload format version 2.0) with a Cognito authorizer. All routes are currently set to be authorized by an admin role, which I understood to map from a Cognito group.
I'm using quarkus-hibernate-orm-rest-data-panache which I understood to not be reactive.
When deploying the application (lambda handler is io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest) it seems the API authentication is successful (Bearer token in the authorization header) because Cognito is allowing the request through to the lambda.
However, the response is always 401. Setting QUARKUS_LOG_LEVEL to DEBUG shows the following entry in CloudWatch logs:
DEBUG [io.qua.ver.htt.run.sec.HttpAuthenticator] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Authentication has not been done, returning HTTP status 401

My questions are: why is the application returning a 401? Do I need to be handling the JWT from Cognito? I wasn't expecting vert.x to be involved, is there another dependency that is causing this? Is this an expected part of the request/response lifecycle?
My reading of the AWS Lambda Quarkus docs, specifically the following phrase is that I shouldn't need any more configuration:

When you invoke an HTTP request on the API Gateway, the Gateway turns that HTTP request into a JSON event document that is forwarded to a Quarkus Lambda. The Quarkus Lambda parses this json and converts in into an internal representation of an HTTP request that can be consumed by any HTTP framework Quarkus supports (Jakarta REST, servlet, Reactive Routes).

The build.gradle (test excluded):
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    // Deployment as an AWS Lambda behind an AWS HTTP v2 API Gateway
    // Breaks the dev UI, see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23014
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda-http'
    // JSON request and response handling
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-jackson'
    // OpenAPI Swagger Docs
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    // Database entity mapping and rest json mapping
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-rest-data-panache'
    // Entity validation
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator'
    // Database connection
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal'
    implementation 'software.amazon.jdbc:aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper:2.3.7'
    // Database entity versioning and auditing
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-envers'
    // Dependency Injection
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    // Security
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-security'
    // AWS SDKs
    implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.26.9"))
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:rds'
}

The application.properties file:
# Core

quarkus.analytics.disabled=true
quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0
quarkus.http.root-path=/default/v1/
quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/q/
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
# Security
quarkus.security.jaxrs.default-roles-allowed=admin
# Custom Credential provider
#
# AWS RDS IAM authentication tokens are only valid for 15 mins
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=software.amazon.jdbc.Driver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:aws-wrapper:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5678/app?user=abc&password=abc

# AWS Lambda
quarkus.snapstart.enable=true
# AWS Lambda Cognito JWT group mapping to Quarkus roles
# https://quarkus.io/guides/aws-lambda-http#security-integration
quarkus.lambda-http.enable-security=true

Some additional notes:

Am using the AWS Advanced JDBC Wrapper to connect to a PostgreSQL RDS instance with RDS IAM Credentials.

